# Number of columns is not fixed

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

In my project, I'm creating a enrollment system using c#.net. The problem I am facing now is I have a feature that add subjects to certain students. I have really no idea how to store to database(mysql) the dynamic number of columns and how to retrieve the save data in database. Hope you can help me. I'm really having a hard time here. Thank you

Comment: Don't add columns, add rows to a separate table (SubjectsTable). In the SubjectsTable, you will have a Foreign Key to the Students table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a Subjects table something like:

```
Subjects (Id, StudentId, SubjectName, SubjectValue)
```

Now you can add as many subjects as you want for a student.

Comment: Okay I wall make it as the solution.

Comment: 1 more thing dude. how can I make it as the answer?

Comment: I can;t change the number 0 to 1 by clicking the up arrow. But I check the check mark

Comment: now that you have reputation over 10, you can vote up